# How can I have the UNIQUE() function to insert lines automatically to prevent the #REF error?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a google-sheet file with 2 sheets : one is called data and filled by a google-app-script project. It's composed of a column called url where one url can be displayed multiple times.

Then I have a 2nd sheet called production where my column A is equal to =Unique(data!A:A) so I have distinct values for url column.

This works fine. However my issue is when I reach the number of lines in production sheet, I have to insert manually 1 000 lines for the UNIQUE function to work properly ; otherwise I have the #REF error.

As my google-app-script runs automatically every day I don't need to open my google sheet and I would like for the UNIQUE function to insert automatically the lines it needs.

Does anyone know how if it's possible ?

Many thanks

Comment: Would you be able to provide your sample sheet, with your initial output, and also your expected output so that we can further help you. You may use this [anonymous sheet maker](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) to create your reproducible example without your email being exposed.

Comment: Did you write the google-app-script code?

Comment: yes I wrote the google-app-script code. But my issue is not a google-app-script one it's google sheet with the UNIQUE() function

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution by inserting blank lines in the production sheet with google app script. Not ideal but it works